# $ABCD$ is perpendicular trapezoid. $|AB| = 5, |DC| = 1, A(EFCD) = S_1 \space cm^2, A(ABFE) = S_2 \space cm^2$ and $S_1 = S_2$

Tags: geometry

[image]

$ABCD$ is perpendicular trapezoid. $|AB| = 5, |DC| = 1, A(EFCD) = S_1 \space cm^2, A(ABFE) = S_2 \space cm^2$ and $S_1 = S_2$ What is the $|EF| = x?$

This question seems too confused.

Comment: Does perpendicular trapezoid here just mean AB perpendicular to AD, and AD perpendicular to DC?

Comment: @coffeemath All I understand is $ABCD$ is trapezoid and probs as you said.

Comment: I'm still thinking on it but couldn't find anything makes sense

Comment: Couldn't anyone solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, we can say $S_1 = S_2 = 12S$. Then if we unite the extension of $AD$ and $BC$ at point $G$, we have 
$$\frac{A(GDC)}{A(GAB)} = \bigg(\frac{|DC|}{|AB|}\bigg)^2 = \frac{1}{25}$$
So we can say $A(GDC) = S$ (That's why in the beginning, I defined $S_1 = S_2 = 12S$). Now by a similar argument, since $\Delta GDC \sim \Delta GFE$, we have
$$\bigg(\frac{|DC|}{|EF|}\bigg)^2 = \frac{A(GDC)}{A(GFE)} \implies \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{13} \implies x = \sqrt{13}$$

Comment: Please take a look at the comment  I have placed as an answer because I was in need for a place for my graphics.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a comment showing an aspect that could look a little paradoxical.

This will be understood by looking at the two displayed figures.

[image]
[image]

We see that in fact, triangle $ABG$ can be arbitrarily "high", with the same base $5$ and a same segment length $EF=\sqrt{13}$ as established in the nice proof by @ArsenBerk. 
More precisely, $EF$ is (apart fixed lengths $AB=5$ and $DC=1$) the unique length in the figure which can be given a value.

Comment: This is a really nice analysis as well as an interesting point. You explained *what* you noticed in a nice way but may I ask you *how* did you notice something like this? I'm asking it because making an analysis like this one needs a lot of attention, I'm impressed :)

Comment: I am happy you ask this question. Here is how I found that something wasn't getting right : I tried to give a name to the different lengths $a=GD, b=ED, c=AE, u=GC,v=CF,w=FD$ and I wrote  all the equations I could $a^2+1=u^2, (u+v)^2+x^2=(a+d)^2,$ etc. and gave it to grind to Mathematica, which invariantly answered "no solution". Then I tried to understand...

Comment: Oh, I never thought about the equation systems, it's still surprising though. So I should thank you I guess for such a nice determination, that made be really excited in the late of this night :)